# Create repeating int sub-index in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Sorry a noob question here,
I am trying to get create multiple index dataframes, however the first value could repeat but I need the second value to restart with every different value from the first one.

For example:

```
idx1    idx2    data
0       0        ...
0       1
0       2
1       0
1       1
1       2
2       0
2       1
...     ...
```

Also I am getting the idx1 from the dataframe and creating the idx2 for future merging, so I dont know how many times is the idx repeating itself before changing to the next number. It could repeat itself 2 times or 8 times for a different dataframe:

```
idx1    idx2    data
0       0        ...
0       1
0       2
0       3
1       0
1       1
1       2
1       3
2       0
2       1
...     ...
```

Does someone know how I can create this kind of subindex(idx2)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group by `idx1` using [`.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and then use [`cumcount()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) to generate the serial number within the group, as follows:

```
df['idx2'] = df.groupby('idx1').cumcount()
```

### Demo

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'idx1': [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2]})

print(df)

   idx1
0     0
1     0
2     0
3     1
4     1
5     1
6     2
7     2

df['idx2'] = df.groupby('idx1').cumcount()

print(df)


   idx1  idx2
0     0     0
1     0     1
2     0     2
3     1     0
4     1     1
5     1     2
6     2     0
7     2     1
```